# Adding TableRow dynamically and retrieving/setting from edittext, viewtext

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view, row

I want to add table rows dynamically to my layout, the rows will be added to a **RelativeLayout** called **main_ScrollView_Container**

The problems I have are that:

1. The added rows are stacked on top each other and not below each other in order added.
2. How can I retrieve the added rows so I can read/write to the **EditText** *input* and **TextView** *output* of each row that I have added?

My oncreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

    // the inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // the item to inflate
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_ScrollView_Container);
    // the item to inflate with

    View tableRow = inflater.inflate(R.xml.my_row, relativeLayout, false);
    relativeLayout.addView(tableRow, 0);

    tableRow = inflater.inflate(R.xml.my_row, relativeLayout, false);
    relativeLayout.addView(tableRow, 1);

    tableRow = inflater.inflate(R.xml.my_row, relativeLayout, false);
    relativeLayout.addView(tableRow, 2);

    tableRow = inflater.inflate(R.xml.my_row, relativeLayout, false);
    relativeLayout.addView(tableRow, 3);

    // retrieve/set values to the EditText input
    // retrieve/set values to the TextView output
}
```

I got this my_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/input"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/output"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
```

and my layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/main_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_ScrollView_Container"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should probably be using `R.layout` rather than `R.xml` to organize and reference your layout files. There are *many* types of xml resources in your project alone - it's a good idea to subcategorize them.

Secondly, when you call `relativeLayout.addView(tableRow, 0);` you are in fact adding `tableRow` at the *0th position* of the layout (the top). Also, since you are adding the rows into a `RelativeLayout`, it's no surprise that they are stacking on top of each other. You might want to use a vertically oriented `LinearLayout` instead, which will take care of vertically arranging the rows from top to bottom.

Thirdly, once you have inflated your row view, you can access its subviews like this:

```
View tableRow = inflater.inflate(R.xml.my_row, relativeLayout, false);
EditText inputBox = (EditText) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.input);
TextView outputBox = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.output);
```

Remember, you can call `findViewById` on any `View` to access its subviews - providing they have IDs.

Comment: Nice, 1 and 2 in your answer I will do.  

About my second question, I dont want to access/edit right after I have created them, I would like to do that later, I guess I need to save every dynamic added view in a list to access them later?  
As every row has a name: @+id/tableRow and same with EditText and TextView have already set id's then I guess I will always get the view of the first id of the one that happens to be first in androids internal list.